# How to make slider text to appear in next row

Tags: css, overflow

I am using a slider and my long text comes in a single line. How can I make to appear in next row?

What css property should I use?

Please check ss.

[image: Screen Shot of my Slider]

Comment: I think the so-called **ss** is not enough.

Comment: I would throw in a `<br />` ... dont know with just that screen shot.

Comment: I guess you have a `white-space: nowrap` on some parent element (maybe to force all elements of your carousel to stay in one line): try to define `white-space: normal` for that paragraph. (but without code is hard to tell)

Comment: =/ How do you make it "Code" in a comment?? lol

Comment: @Mike you can use a pair of tick signs ` (the key right before the key 1 on your keyboard) to enclose the code.

Comment: @KingKing - Thanks so much! Been wondering that for a while now. haha

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thanks So much the white-space: normal works for me

Comment: @Umar I've just overhauled my crystal ball

Answer (score 0):

you can us css div class and height will be auto with width in % and place on a div with relative position, margin and pedding..